# socket.emit does not work for other open connections

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am doing tic tac toe multiplayer game using node.js but i am facing the following problem

1> The alert does not pop up in other open connections

//app.js

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server,{});
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

socket.on('blockClicked',function(data){
    socket.emit('newPositions',data.value);
});

socket.on('disconnect',function(){
    delete SOCKET_LIST[socket.id];
});

});


//index.html

socket.on('newPositions',function(data){
        blockSelected(data);
        alert("recieved"+data);
});
```

where have i gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are emitting to a single `socket` (client) when you call `socket.emit('newPositions', data.value);`. 
You can emit to all sockets by using `io.sockets.emit('newPositions', data.value);`

Comment: yep. That was the problem :)

Comment: By the way .. how to pair two players to play the game